# Have a Screen whereI once click on the text box the up and down arrow will become visible to click but it is not clicking and is not throwing a error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I added this piece of code: Any inputs to get this working would be helpful

```
WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='number'] 
[formcontrolname='sample']"));
     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", inputElement);
     inputElement.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP);
```

Tried with Actions Class,.click method,javascript click ,Keys.UpArrow changed the xpath still it is not clicking on the Arrorw button

Below is the DOM :

```
      <input type="number" formcontrolname="sample" class="form-control form-control-sm ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
```